# How are moments used in crystallization population balance calculations?

Tags: statistics, ordinary-differential-equations, logic

For example in this paper http://konyvtar.uni-pannon.hu/hjic/HJIC35_07_17.pdf method of moments is used to describe crystal size and other parameters. Can somebody explain how to relate normal method of moments to this crystallization process as given in the paper?

Answer (score 0):

Their use of moments is slightly misleading. I assume you are looking at $\mu_{1,2}$, which they call a joint moment. But really, since both are dimensions of crystals, the formula for $\mu_{1,2}$ just finds the expected value of the olume of a crystal that is $L_1$ long in image dimension and $L_2$ long in the ther two dimensions. So although it technically is a moment, it should be interpreted as the expected value of a volume.